# interop netbeans wcf with validation

Tags: wcf, netbeans, interop, microsoft-metro

Im building a App that uses a Wcf Service and i need it to be interop with java.
right now im using netbeans metro as a client.
when using basichttpbinding without doing something special(standard wcf application) its all smooth sailing.

the moment i tried to introduce username and pass validation i got into to a true hell.
the main problem is certifications and the ws protocol.
-so i decided to go for the new express bindings to help me out ans used this tutorial:
http://webservices20.blogspot.be/2011/06/test-drive-shiny-new-wcf-interop.html
i tried and failed over and over again.

so my question is.

-is there a way of using a simple username password validation method without all the mess i get from certification ?

-is there a tutorial or working solution that will work in netbeans

if i realy have to i will buy a ssl but for testing purposes i realy would like to avoid that.

thx,

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to use basichttpbinding, which you have already got to work.

Send the user name and password as part of the message.

Basichttpbinding can use SSL encryption (transport security), you should use this so that your username and passord are not sent over the wire in clear text.